# How to select columns using a wildcard search on column names in SPSS Modeler

Tags: spss-modeler

I am doing time series analyis predicting sales for  a large amount of products. After executing the time series node, I get a table containing the original sales data and predicted values with a suffix "$TS-" before the product name. Now I would like to select / filter only those columns containing a "$TS-" in the column name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy or straightforward way to do something like this. The simplest way, in my opinion, would be to

1. Add a 'Filter' node after the time series model nugget
2. Use the *funnel* button to "Remove all Fields"
3. Select to include each of the individual fields that you would like to keep
4. Make sure that the node is set to *Include fields by default*

If fields are added to your original data sources or if new fields are derived in the stream, you'll have to go back to this node and remove them, so it's not ideal.

The alternative is to use a stream script to change the inclusion and removal of the fields within a "Filter" node. The script below will search for a "Filter" node with the name given by the variable `filterNodeName` and search for fields with the prefix given by the variable `fieldNamePrefix` and keep only the fields that match the designated prefix.

```
filterNodeName  = "TS Fields Only"
fieldNamePrefix = "$TS-"

diagram = modeler.script.diagram()
# Find the 'Filter' node
renameFieldsNode = diagram.findByType('filternode', filterNodeName)
# Get the input data model - the fields that go into the 'Filter' node
fields = renameFieldsNode.getInputDataModel()
# Loop through all of the fields
for field in fields:
  fieldName = field.getColumnName()
  if fieldName.startswith(fieldNamePrefix):
    # If the field name starts with the designated prefix then include the field
    renameFieldsNode.setKeyedPropertyValue('include', fieldName, True)
  else:
    # Otherwise do not include the field
    renameFieldsNode.setKeyedPropertyValue('include', fieldName, False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and detailed answer! It works perfectly fine!

Comment: I just came up with another solution for this problem: transpose the data, add a select node and do the wildcard search on the rows and transpose again.

Comment: @FelixWalther - That is a good and creative solution!
The method doesn't work in all scenarios - like if you wish to preserve both text and numeric fields - but for your purpose, it should do the trick.